# 17.04 Graphics issues... Black textures

Tags: drivers, graphics

I upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and I'm using Unity3d to develop some games.
After the upgrade, all the textures are black.

[image: (Example... Checkers)]

Running the application on another PC/device works fine.

My system has an [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8330].

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In unity3d, If I change the compression of the textures to high or none, they show up...  However there some that I cannot change, and it messes with what I can do in the editor.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. Tried the default drivers, oibaf and padoka without love. Some games work such as Speed runners and Minecraft while Eurotrucker 2, Super chicken horse and Stellaris doesn't. Have you found a solution?